# jQuery change event being called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I have a form with some input and select boxes, each has `class="myClass"`. I also have the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myClass").change(function() {
        alert('bla');
    })
});
```

I dont understand why after each change in select box or input box, this function is being called twice.
What's wrong here?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: As fl00r indicated, it would be helpful to see more of your code.  Double function calls are often a symptom of unintentionally attaching your handler twice.

Comment: thank you, Uberstein just showed me my wrong

Answer (score 52, accepted):

All I can think of is that you used the same class on the form itself. if so, remove the myClass style from your form tag.

Corrected :
http://jsfiddle.net/rY6Gq/1/

Faulty one with double alert:
http://jsfiddle.net/rY6Gq/

Comment: It's a good idea to check if two event listeners have been created. If the code ran twice, or if the file was included twice on the page, the event will happen twice.

Comment: @RaisinBranCrunch Thanks for the tip. My problem was that the file was included twice.

Answer (score 53):

e.stopImmediatePropagation(); is what worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myClass").change(function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        alert('bla');
    })
});
```

Comment: I don't know why in my case this happened (the "change" event being fired twice), but I do know that your solution worked for me!

Comment: It works like a charm!!

Comment: that saves the day.

Answer (score 12):

Its a bug,
You'd add

```
$("#some_id").unbind('change');
```

before any change call

Answer (score 5):

It happens when the same class or whatever attribute you are binding also has the same name parent or child. Obviously, when you change a child, parent also gets changed (its child changes). If they have the same class or attribute, it should fire twice.
For example, in the following if you bind to "myClass", it will be called twice.

```
<div class="myclass">
<select class="myClass">   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. for it was a solution. in my case selectpicker generated a div with the same class as on my initial select tag.

Answer (score 3):

if this occurred in IE, it may be this bug as it was for me:
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6593

updating to jQuery 1.7.1 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me - I had written the `on change event` inside a function.
Moving it to `$(document).ready(function () {});` solved my case.

Answer (score 1):

change like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(".myClass").unbind('change');

    $(".myClass").change(function() {
        alert('bla');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't: http://jsfiddle.net/nfcAS/

Answer (score 0):

The only one that worked for me was unbind before the change check.

```
 $(".select2Component").unbind(); 
    $(".select2Component").change(function() { 
         //code
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**For me none of the  above solution  worked**

but simply I  just Added name in  the select and called the change event by finding the name and it worked for  me

**Old code method was calling twice :**

```
$(".ddlResponse").on("change",function () {
var $section = $(this).closest('section');
var multiResp = $(this).children("option:selected").map(function (i, v) {
    return this.value;
}).get();

var PreMasterId = $section.attr('PreMasterId');
var queId = $section.attr('queId');
var respId = $section.attr('respId');
var domainId = $section.attr('domainId');
var QueType = $section.attr('QueType');

SubmitPreResponse(domainId, respId, PreMasterId, queId, multiResp.join(), QueType);
});
```

**New code  which is working fine  :**

```
$("select[name='singleSelection']").on("change",function () {
var $section = $(this).closest('section');
var multiResp = $(this).children("option:selected").map(function (i, v) {
    return this.value;
}).get();

var PreMasterId = $section.attr('PreMasterId');
var queId = $section.attr('queId');
var respId = $section.attr('respId');
var domainId = $section.attr('domainId');
var QueType = $section.attr('QueType');

SubmitPreResponse(domainId, respId, PreMasterId, queId, multiResp.join(), QueType);
});
```

I hope it will help  someone  else as  well .....

Happy coding  #rctechlife

Answer (score -1):

Try debugging the code in Firebug rather than alerting. It may be loosing the focus and returning it is causing the appearance of two changes when there isn't two happening

Comment: plus i know this has happened to a friend but i'm not sure what browser he was using at the time